# Use alpha values provided in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I would like to use the explicit values for the alpha level.

```
head(D)

    x  y group  alpha
  1 1 18     A   0.40   <~~~~
  2 2 18     A   0.44
  3 3 18     A   0.47
  4 1 18     A   0.51
  5 2 21     B   0.55
  6 3 21     B   0.58
  ...
```

However, ggplot is scaling the alpha levels.  I can override this using `scale_alpha_continuous(range = range(D$alpha))`, but this becomes a nuisance when creating the graph programmatically.

**Is there a direct way to tell ggplot NOT to scale alpha?** (instead of telling it what range to scale to)

[image]

#### Reproducible Exmple

```
library(ggplot)
library(gridExtra)
(D <- data.frame(x=rep(1:3, 4), y=rep((6:8)*3, each=4), group=rep(c("A","B", "C"), each=4),  alpha=round(seq(.4, .8, length.out=12), 2)))

P <- ggplot(data=D, aes(x=x, y=y, alpha=alpha)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue") + theme(legend.position="bottom") + facet_grid(group ~. )

### Adding  scale_alpha_continuous
P.manually_scaled <- P + scale_alpha_continuous(range=range(D$alpha))

grid.arrange( P + ggtitle("INCORRECT")
             , P.manually_scaled + ggtitle("CORRECT")
             , ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have actual alpha, color, ..., values then you should use `..identity()` scales. This will tell `ggplot()` to assign alpha values as they are in your data frame and not to scale them.

```
ggplot(data=D, aes(x=x, y=y, alpha=alpha)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue") + 
         facet_grid(group ~. ) +
         scale_alpha_identity()
```